# Accesing tabCapture inside the browser (puppeteer)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, puppeteer, chromium

I want to access to TabCapture Api inside a browser (specifically inside puppeteer).

Can I do it somehow or this is API only exposed to extensions?

If it's possible, how I can do it?

P.S I just want to capture the audio of page, thanks in advance for your help

Comment: It's only for extensions. You'll have to use standard web audio in an injected js code.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you provide an example ?/

Comment: Examples should be easy to google up: 1) using web audio, 2) running arbitrary javascript in puppeteer. I didn't do it myself so this is as far as I can help.